# Binding Keys to Move an Image

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am working on a game for a school project and as one step I have to bind keys to the image that will add/subtract from the x-y axis. However the way I have done it does not seem to work and instead of adding by a small amount increases the x/y by a lot and teleports the image away off of the screen.

The KeyListener code

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == 87) {
        up = true ;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 65) {
            left = true ; 
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 68) {
            right = true ;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 83) {
            down = true ;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == 87) {
        up = false ;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 65) {
        left = false; 
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 68) {
        right = false ;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 83) {
        down = false ;
    }

}
```

The Game Loop

```
public void run() {

    while(running) {

        //Player movement
        if (up) {
            y++ ;
        }
        if (left) {
            x-- ;
        }
        if (right) {
            x++;
        }
        if (down) {
            y-- ;
        }
        //Player movement

    }
}
```

Graphical Loop

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Graphical loop start
    g.drawImage(Player, x, y, null) ;       

    //Graphical loop end
    repaint();
```

Comment: This could be due to the speed of your updates. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Also consider using the key bindings API instead of `KeyListener`. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: As a side note, you should check your braces in `keyPressed`. I edited to correct your code formatting and noticed there might be a bug. (`left`/`right`/`down` are inside the `up` block.)

Comment: `e.getKeyCode() == 83`  Don't use 'magic numbers' like `83`.  There are constants defined for each key, and they (the numbers) might change per JRE implementation or OS.

Answer (score 3):

The code works just the way it's supposed to. You only forgot one thing: the `while`-loop for moving the image is running a lot faster than you seem to expect it to run. Simply insert a `Thread.sleep(someDelay)` to make the loop run slower and the image should move with a more "userfriendly" speed.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't answer your question but:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == 87)
```

Don't use "magic numbers". People don't know what "87" means. Use the field names provided by the API:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
```

Also, in your paintComponent() method you have:

```
//Graphical loop end
repaint();
```

Don't ever invoke repaint() within a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop. Get rid of that code.

Comment: The repaint is so the image moves and updates based on the x and y axis. Without it it doesn't move whatsoever as it is never updated.

Comment: @Sumtinlazy The comment was about repainting *within the painting method*, not a recommendation to avoid repainting at all. You should call `repaint()` when the state changes (or from a game loop with appropriate delays, if the screen contents are expected to change almost every iteration). `repaint()` from `paintComponent()` is an effectively infinite loop as stated, and is queuing painting as fast as the system is capable. It's better to have some delay in between as the screen can't be updated arbitrarily fast anyway.

Comment: Would I have to create a method that would call repaint( ) and how would I repaint a specific image.

Comment: @Sumtinlazy, basically, when you change the value of x/y you need to do a repaint(). So you can add the repaint() method in your `while (running)` loop. Of course as Paul has already mention you still need the loop to run slower by adding the Thread.sleep().